# Azure Container Apps - Number of Replicas per second

Tags: azure, logging, azure-container-apps

We're analysing the scaling behavior of different serverless services for a small thesis. In this context I created a Container App, defined the scaling based on HTTP rules and we also have a scenario in Artillery for load testing. Now would like to monitor the number of incoming request as well as the number of replicas on a finer granularity than 1min (The default metrics provided by Azure only have granularity of 1min). Is there any possibility to query this in Log Analytics or elsewhere?

thanks,
michael

Checked the provided metrics in Azure Portal
Browsed the Log Analytics sites

Answer (score 0):

> monitor the number of incoming request as well as the number of replicas on a finer granularity than 1min

I have created container app in azure portal by using log analytics workspace. check below:

[image]

I have added HTTP scaling by followed below steps. check below:

[image]
[image]

By using below query in Log analytics workspace to get the combination of replica count and request count. check below:

```
let replicaCountQuery = AppPlatformLogs | where Category == "ContainerInstance" | summarize ReplicaCount = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m); let requestCountQuery = AppPlatformLogs | where Category == "HttpRequest" | summarize RequestCount = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m);  replicaCountQuery | join kind=outer (requestCountQuery) on TimeGenerated | project TimeGenerated, ReplicaCount, RequestCount | order by TimeGenerated
```

- Counts the number of container instances `ReplicaCount` based on the "ContainerInstance" logs.
- Counts the number of incoming HTTP requests `RequestCount` based on the "HttpRequest" logs.
- Joins the ReplicaCount and RequestCounts of data on the time bin, projecting the relevant fields, and ordering the results by time.